# Predefined variable substitution in VSCode tasks user input

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Looking at the [documentation for VSCode variable substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference), I was expecting the following `tasks.json` to perform variable substitution in the pick list when using the `chooseDirectory` code, but it just selects the literal string `${fileDirname}` instead.

Can I get the substituted text to appear in the user selection menu?

```json
{
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "command": "cmd",
   "args": ["/c"],
   "tasks": [
      {
         "label": "The task",
         "command": "my_batch_file.bat",
         "type": "shell",
         "args": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            "${input:chooseDirectory}"
         ],
         "problemMatcher": []
      }
   ],
   "inputs": [
      {
         "id": "chooseDirectory",
         "description": "Select the Directory",
         "type": "pickString",
         "options": ["option1", "${fileDirname}"],
         "default": "option1"
      }
   ]
}
```

When the task executes, this is what gets executed:

```
> Executing task: my_batch_file.bat C:\My\Workspace\Directory ${fileDirname} <
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue suggests that variable substitution is currently not supported for `inputs`, but might be added sometime in the future:

[consider to allow for variable substitution in the inputs section (#64358)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/64358)

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, it's useful to see independent confirmation that I wasn't going mad ;-)

Comment: For reference, it was added in a release shortly afterwards (1.30.0) and it now works just as you'd expect.

Comment: Well spotted @Gama11. I'm retracting my comment above, ;-). I got round the problem in a different way and forgot that I didn't use this functionality in the end. I think it was the `${input:xxx}` functionality that was added in 1.30.0 (to which I referred).