# How to resolve variables inside vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I am creating an extension that will expose a command to be executed through tasks executors from vscode and I would like to use the native resolution for variables.
For example:

In my tasks configuration I want to use it like this:

```
   "inputs": [
       {
            "id": "specInput",
            "type": "command",
            "command": "shellCommand.execute",
            "args": {
                "command": "find cypress/integration -type f",
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/e2e/"
            }
        }
   ]
```

Relevant code:

```
const commandHandler = (args: ShellCommandOptions) => {
    const workspaceFolder = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders && vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath;
    const cwd = args.cwd || workspaceFolder;
}
```

Full extension code can be found [here](https://github.com/augustocdias/vscode-shell-command/blob/master/src/extension.ts).

The problem is, when the `cwd` parameter arrives at my extension, the `workspaceFolder` is not resolved. How could I resolve it? I didn't want to re-implement vscode's features.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308560/predefined-variable-substitution-in-vscode-tasks-user-input

Comment: @Gama11 related but not duplicated. I want to know how to do it in my extension code, through the API.

Comment: I don't think VSCode exposes any API for that. There's an issue related to that here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/70769